# How to get USSD code response in my ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, ussd

I want to develop an iOS application to get the response to a USSD code whenever the user dials it. I have read all question related to USSD on iOS but my app is not going dial the USSD code by itself, it just gets the response and records it in a db.

If there any article or tutorial to get started?
Can I even do this on iOS operating system?

Note: I have developed the android version of this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this on iOS. Apps are sandboxed and do not generally have access to data from other applications (there are specific methods that allows apps to share data, such as the pasteboard), so your app cannot access data from the phone app.

Answer (score 2):

You can call *#06# programmatically. Don`t forget to replace * to %2a and # to %23. ENJOY